# How to use data-binding between controller and templateUrl?

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to drag an image and drop it on web browser. After drop the image, I get the base64 data in controller and I want to pass the data into the templateUrl. Here is my code:

**Controller:**

```
//After drop the image, pass the base64 data to dataUrl
$scope.dataUrl = e.target.result;
```

**Directive:**

```
.directive('crop', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'img-token/views/img-crop.html',
        scope: {
            width: '=',
            height: '=',
            dataUrl: '@'
        },
        link: function (scope, elements, attrs) {

            $(elements[0]).children().first().jWindowCrop({
                targetWidth: width,
                targetHeight: height,

                }
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

**img-crop.html**

```
<img class="crop_me" ng-src="{{dataUrl}}"/>
```

**index.html**

```
<crop width="300" height="300" dataUrl="{{dataUrl}}"></crop>
```

I want to bind the dataUrl between controller and the templateUrl, is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: Try changing `dataUrl: '@'` to `dataUrl: '='`

Comment: [try this](http://plnkr.co/edit/tJ9gTPc9nxubREu36ZJz?p=preview)

Comment: Can you show how you declare the directive?

Comment: @runTarm I tried before, didn't work

Comment: Could you show the html part that use the `crop` directive?

Comment: @runTarm Sure, I just did it

Comment: @evc Your code is working because you put the url in the controller. What I'm trying to do is to get the data after you drop the picture, so I need to use data binding to get the data. But I don't know why I can't pass the data into the templateUrl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found why your code does not work.

1. There is an error in your directive's link function, the `width` and `height` aren't defined. They'are in the scope, so the code should be:

   ```
   $(elements[0]).children().first().jWindowCrop({
     targetWidth: scope.width,
     targetHeight: scope.height,
   });
   ```
2. In directive definition, scope object properties have to be in camelCase `dataUrl`, but in html attribute it have to be in kebabCase `data-url`:

   ```
   <crop width="300" height="300" data-url="{{dataUrl}}"></crop>
   ```
3. This one is the most tricky, for any attribute that begin with `data-`, angular will strip the prefix out before using it, so the `data-url` from 2) will become `url` eventually. The logic is there to allow one to write an angular app that stricly conform to the HTML specification. A workaround is to use `data-data-url` or just use an another name.

   ```
   <crop width="300" height="300" data-data-url="{{dataUrl}}"></crop>
   ```

Hope this helps!

**Example plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/uo65UVYaF24RBUBeJ5jA?p=preview